# Problem using Ajax with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to add Ajax controls to my VS 2010 project for the first time. I have previously gotten it to work when I used VS2008. I keep getting this exception:

Error   56  The type 'System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Here’s what I did. I downloaded the ajax 4 toolkit and added a reference to the project. I also added a reference to system.web extension to my project. When I do this these lines get added to my web.config

```
<assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies></compilation>
```

I added these lines to my aspx file.

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```

And

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender runat="server" Id="txtDateOfBirth_CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="txtDateOfBirth"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Etc.
I also backed off and tried ajax 3.5, this didn’t help. I did notice that the ajax dll is 4.1 while the 'System.Web.Extensions is 4.0. I don’t know if this matters but I cannot find ajax 4.0 or 'System.Web.Extensions 4.1.

Thank once again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution but a recommendation: stay away from the Ajax toolkit or you are asking for trouble; use jquery instead (seriously, I have been down this road).

Comment: I want use ajax so I can create edit masks for my text boxes for fields such as telephone number and zip code. Can Jquery accomplish this? If so can you point me to some examples.

Comment: Absolutely! Here is the jquery plugin link: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maskedinput and here is the plugin's homepage: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ (it has usage examples/demo/etc.)

Comment: I was able to use jquery to solve my problem, so I will mark this as answer. I would still like to know why I can't get ajax to work.